# Python: next() is not recognized

Tags: python, iterator

When I do `next(ByteIter, '')<<8` in python, I got a name error saying

> "global name 'next' is not defined"

I'm guessing this function is not recognized because of python version?  My version is 2.5.

Comment: It was introduced in py2.6 http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next)

> next(iterator[, default])
>
> ```
> Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its next() method. 
> If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is
> exhausted, otherwise StopIteration is raised.
>
> New in version 2.6.
> ```

So yes, it does require version 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

though you could call ByteIter.next() in 2.6. This is not recommended however, as the method has been renamed in python 3 to **next**().

Answer (score 1):

The [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) wasn't added until Python 2.6.

There is a workaround, however. You can call `.next()` on Python 2 iterables:

```
try:
    ByteIter.next() << 8
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

`.next()` throws a `StopIteration` and you cannot specify a default, so you need to catch `StopIteration` explicitly.

You *can* wrap that in your own function:

```
_sentinel = object()
def next(iterable, default=_sentinel):
    try:
        return iterable.next()
    except StopIteration:
        if default is _sentinel:
            raise
        return default
```

This works just like the Python 2.6 version:

```
>>> next(iter([]), 'stopped')
'stopped'
>>> next(iter([]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in next
StopIteration
```