# Python Edit CSV headers

Tags: python

I have the following data from a csv file called temp.

```
Item,Description,Base Price,Available
2000-000-000-300,AC - CF/M Series Green For Black Hood,299.99,3
2000-000-000-380,AC - CF/M Series Green For White Hood,299.99,3
```

I need to change the headers to read

```
Item Number,Item Description,List Price,QTY Available
```

I have been searching similar questions on here and haven't a solution that I can understand since I am relatively new to python programming. So far I have:

```
import csv
import os

inputFileName = "temp.csv"
outputFileName = os.path.splitext(inputFileName)[0] + "_modified.csv"

with open(inputFileName) as inFile, open(outputFileName, "w") as outfile:
    r = csv.reader(inFile)
    w = csv.writer(outfile)
```

Which I know only reads the original file and then will write to _modified. How do I select the current headers and then change them so that they write to the new file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The headers are just another row of CSV data. Just write them as a new row to the output followed by the rest of the data from the input file.

```
import csv
import os

inputFileName = "temp.csv"
outputFileName = os.path.splitext(inputFileName)[0] + "_modified.csv"

with open(inputFileName, 'rb') as inFile, open(outputFileName, 'wb') as outfile:
    r = csv.reader(inFile)
    w = csv.writer(outfile)

    next(r, None)  # skip the first row from the reader, the old header
    # write new header
    w.writerow(['Item Number', 'Item Description', 'List Price', 'QTY Available'])

    # copy the rest
    for row in r:
        w.writerow(row)
```

For Python 3, use:

```
with open(inputFileName, newline='') as inFile, open(outputFileName, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
```

and you may have to specify an encoding for your data.

Comment: When I try to run the script I get TypeError: writerow() takes exactly one argument (4 given).

Comment: The usual way to call `next` in Python 3 is `next(r)` (one parameter).  For those who are using Python 2, it would be `r.next()`.  (I can deduce from OP's comment that he didn't have a problem with your `next` invocation, though. ;)

Comment: @barkl3y: Yeah, group all the arguments into a single list or tuple first. (Just put a pair of square brackets or a second set of parens around the arguments.)

Comment: @JohnY: `next()` takes a default. If `r` is *empty*, `next(r)` throws `StopIteration`, while `next(r, None)` returns the default `None` instead.

Comment: @JohnY: and `next()` works great in Python 2 as well. By using `next()` your code becomes compatible between Python 2 and 3. In Python 3 you could also call `r.__next__()` but using `next()` is more pythonic.

Comment: Ah, old habit. `next()` was introduced in Python 2.6, and one of the platforms I use Python on was stuck at 2.3.3 until only recently.

Comment: @JohnY: It is easy enough to [backport `next()` to older versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224901/python-next-is-not-recgonized/16225180#16225180)

Comment: @barkl3y: My code copies the input file exactly, except for the very first row. If you see blank lines, then your input had blank lines.

Comment: How come does the resulting file have a blank line between the two original lines?

Comment: @MartijnPieters is there a way to remove the blank line that's in-between? My original file appears as I had posted.

Comment: @barkl3y: are you using Python 3?  If so, you need to use `open(inputFileName, newline='')` and `open(outputFileName, "w", newline='')` instead (see [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html#module-contents)).

Comment: @barkl3y: okay, then try `open(.., "rb")` and `open(output.., "wb")`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use the `fileinput` module to update the file in place:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input('temp', inplace=True):
    if fileinput.isfirstline():
        print 'Item Number,Item Description,List Price,QTY Available'
    else:
        print line,
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) for this:

```
import fileinput
import sys
import os

inputFileName = "temp.csv"
outputFileName = os.path.splitext(inputFileName)[0] + "_modified.csv"

with open(outputFileName, "w") as outfile:
    for line in fileinput.input(
        [inputFileName],
        inplace=False):
        if fileinput.isfirstline():
            outfile.write('Item Number,Item Description,List Price,QTY Available\n')
        else:
            outfile.write(line)
```