# Python Pandas - Write New CSV Header Row without Reading/ReWriting Entire File

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a 27GB CSV file and I want to simply rename the header rows.
Can I do this without reading the entire file into a dataframe and then writing the entire file again?

This is essentially what I want to do, but without re-writing the whole 27GB file.

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename,sep="|",nrows=2)
data.head()

LOC_ID  UPC FW  BOP_U   BOP_$
0   17  438531560821    201712  1   40.0
1   239 438550152328    201719  2   28.8


data.columns = ['WHSE','SKU','PERIOD','QUANTITYONHAND','DOLLARSONHAND']
data.head()


   WHSE           SKU  PERIOD  QUANTITYONHAND  DOLLARSONHAND
0    17  438531560821  201712               1           40.0
1   239  438550152328  201719               2           28.8
```

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4454522/2901002)

Comment: So you want to change the header in the file, on the file system?

Comment: There are certainly easier ways to do this than Pandas or even Python.

Comment: It seems you have to rewrite file - [info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16306879/2901002)

Comment: This is best suited for commandline-like, shell script, instead of using python/pandas just for this.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify there being only a single row with `nrows`.

```
header_df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', index_col=0, nrows=1)
```

As for *re-writing* the file, I don't think you'll get around having to process the entire file to re-write.