# Multiline csv field and Python next(file)

Tags: python, csv, file-io, python-3.4

Input file is standard CSV file with about 200 rows and 70 columns.

I need to rename header according to schema, write it to new file and append data from original file.

However, some fields contain multi-line text and when I use `next(file)` to omit original header, these lines in single field are interpreted as new CSV line (see bellow)

Original file example:

```
+----------------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------------+-----------+
|    Summary     | Issue key | Issue id | Parent id |    Issue Type    |  Status   |
+----------------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------------+-----------+
| Project info 2 | ABCDE     |   326974 | NA        | Approval Request | Completed |
| info continues |           |          |           |                  |           |
| in signle cell |           |          |           |                  |           |
+----------------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------------+-----------+
```

File after output:

```
+================+===========+=========+===========+==================+===========+
|    Summary     | Issue key | Renamed | Parent id |     Renamed      |  Status   |
+================+===========+=========+===========+==================+===========+
| Project info 2 | ABCDE     |  326974 | NA        | Approval Request | Completed |
+----------------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------------+-----------+
| info continues |           |         |           |                  |           |
+----------------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------------+-----------+
| in single cell |           |         |           |                  |           |
+----------------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------------+-----------+
```

and finally, this is the code:

```
with open(self.paths['raw_file_path'], "r", encoding='UTF-8', errors="ignore") as cut_file:
                header = cut_file.readline().strip()
                # header renaming code, works well
                with open(self.paths['head_file_path'], "w", encoding='UTF-8',) as head_file:
                        head_file.write(",".join(header))
                        next(cut_file)
                        for line in cut_file:
                            head_file.write(line)
```

When I dump file per line without `next()`, everything is correct. However, I need to skip the first line (original header).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: use the csv module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, in order to read the csv file, it is better to use `csv` module.

In order to skip the first row you need to use `next(cut_file, None)`

Here is the solution to rename the header easily using `csv` module.
Thanks to the answer in [the following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306819/python-edit-csv-headers)

```
import csv
import os

inputFileName = "test.csv"
outputFileName = "new_file.csv"
separator=','
new_header = next(open('header_file.csv')).split(separator)

with open(inputFileName, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as inFile, open(outputFileName, 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as outfile:
    r = csv.reader(inFile)
    w = csv.writer(outfile)

    next(r, None)  # skip the first row from the reader, the old header
    # write new header
    w.writerow(new_header)

    # copy the rest
    for row in r:
        w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, this is python3 (sorry, should have stated that), so `open` statement is correct. I also tried `next(cut_file, None)`, with no change.

Comment: Ah ok. My answer is tested with python2.7. I will edit it for python3.

Comment: It is `next` and no `skip`

Comment: sorry, typo here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147319/discussion-between-saloua-and-michal).