# Export Elasticsearch results into a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, elasticsearch, export-to-csv

I am trying to export the results that is found using the below query into a CSV on my desktop.

This is my first time using Elasticsearch and cURL so i am confused on how to do this.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(["9200"])

# Replace the following Query with your own Elastic Search Query
res = es.search(index="search", body=
                {
                    "_source": ["DTDT", "TRDT", "SPLE", "RPLE"],
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {"wildcard": {"CN": "TEST1"}}

                            ]
                        }
                    }
}, size=10)

for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
    print(doc)
```

right now when i run this query it returns the name, lastname, address and gender for dave and i want to put the results into a csv on my desktop when i run the query.

i have been reading this link on how to do it but im not sure how to make my query do this - (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

could someone help and show me how to convert my query in exporting a csv PLEASE!

thanks

the output i get is -

```
{'_index': 'search', '_type': 'trades', '_id': '179299804977823744', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'DTDT': '20170928', 'SPLE': '1001', 'RPLE': '1001', 'TRDT': '2017-09-28 17:01:19'}}
```

Comment: Can you please give output of print(doc) ? Couple of lines will do

Comment: the query i have posted i have edited some of the code such as what i am searching for. do you need the original code. the only difference is the column name. I have updated me original post when the output and original code now. thank you for taking a look. im struggling to convert my code into export the results in CSV.

Comment: When you above code and print the result, at last in for loop, that output is required to understand how data is coming.

Comment: thanks for replying quickly, have you seen my updated post with my updated code and out put?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use csv module to write data.

From the output you have given, I am assuming that you want to write data from `_source` to csv file.

**Code :**

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import csv

es = Elasticsearch(["9200"])

# Replace the following Query with your own Elastic Search Query
res = es.search(index="search", body=
                {
                    "_source": ["DTDT", "TRDT", "SPLE", "RPLE"],
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {"wildcard": {"CN": "TEST1"}}

                            ]
                        }
                    }
}, size=10)



with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    header_present  = False
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source'] 
        if not header_present:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
            w.writeheader()
            header_present = True


        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

Comment: you able to show me how to add your code with my code please?

Comment: i got alot of errors

GET http://9200:9200/search/_search?size=10 [status:N/A request:8.984s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):

Comment: File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: sorry i saw what mistak i made, i fixed it and ran the query, it created the CSV file but no data in the file also im getting a error called 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users//.PyCharmCE2017.2/config/scratches/test1.py", line 26, in <module>
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
NameError: name 'my_dict' is not defined

Comment: by the way, i just want to say thank you for helping me, i have been looking at other examples to get this working with columns so i might post another post later but if we get this working i will be grateful!

Comment: Hi Dinesh, sorry to be a pain but i posted a new question relating to CSV - could you take a look i have a feeling you might know what the issue is. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46684252/export-elasticsearch-data-results-into-a-csv-file

Comment: @ Dinesh, thank you so so much, could i ask for another favour? how can i put colum header names? right now there is no header. for example i want to add like first name, second name, address columns header name in the CSV file?

Comment: @ Dinesh, when you get a chance could you help me with on how to rename the columns inside the csv file that is created right now the columns are, DTDT, TRDT, SPLE, RPLE. i would like the columns be created with custom names like date, number etc etc when the query is ran. would you know how to do this?

Comment: Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306819/python-edit-csv-headers

Comment: Let me know if it helps

Comment: i took a look and it is something i want but still stuck, you able to change the code around and show me how its done?

Comment: What is replacement you want for each element in this list ? ["DTDT", "TRDT", "SPLE", "RPLE]

Comment: so for example , DTDT can be dateid, trdt can be date, sple can be superid and rple can be retailpenny, will i can able to add more columns later if needed?

Comment: i hope my last comment made sense in what names i wanted for the columns. thanks!!

Comment: i have figure it out! thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  would you also know how to create my file called 'mycsvfile with the current date & time at the end of the file name for when i run the query the name should be mycsvfile20121012 - 09:00:00?