# Export Elasticsearch data results into a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, elasticsearch, export-to-csv

I would like to export my elastic search data that is being returned from my query to a CSV file. I have been looking everywhere to do this but all my attemps on this is failing on how to do it.

my query is below;

```
import elasticsearch
import unicodedata
import csv

es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(["9200"])
# this returns up to 100 rows, adjust to your needs

res = es.search(index="search", body=
{
    "_source": ["CN", "NCR", "TRDT"],

    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {"wildcard": {
                                        "CN": "TEST*"
                                    }
                                }]
                        }
                    }},size=10)

sample = res['hits']['hits']

# then open a csv file, and loop through the results, writing to the csv
with open('outputfile.tsv', 'wb') as csvfile:

    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t',  # we use TAB delimited, to handle cases where freeform text may have a comma
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    # create column header row
    filewriter.writerow(["CN", "NCR", "TRDT"])    #change the column labels here
    # fill columns 1, 2, 3 with your data
    col1 = hit["some"]["deeply"]["nested"]["field"].decode('utf-8')  #replace these nested key names with your own
    col1 = col1.replace('\n', ' ')
    # col2 = , col3 = , etc...
    for hit in sample:
        filewriter.writerow(col1)
```

could someone fix this code up for it to work please, been spending hours on this to make it work.

the error i am getting when running this is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.PyCharmCE2017.2/config/scratches/trtr.py", line 30, in <module>
    filewriter.writerow(["CN", "NCR", "TRDT"])  # change the column labels here
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `wb` with `w` in `with open('outputfile.tsv', 'wb')` since you are using Python 3.x

Comment: thank you, that fixed that issue but now im getting another, which is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.PyCharmCE2017.2/config/scratches/trtr.py", line 32, in <module>
    col1 = sample["some"]["deeply"]["nested"]["field"].decode('utf-8')  # replace these nested key names with your own
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str