# Writing CSV from Elasticsearch result using python with records exceeding 10000 ?

Tags: python, csv, elasticsearch

Im able to create the CSV using the solution provided here:

[Export Elasticsearch results into a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682018/export-elasticsearch-results-into-a-csv-file)

but problem arises when the records exceeds 10000 (size=10000), is there any way to write all the records?

Comment: I would suggest to look into [pagination](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html), or the [scroll api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html). The [elasticsearch-py scroll helper](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan) might be useful here. Then you can post details about where it's going wrong for you, and people might be able to help.

Comment: thanks, looking into the scroll api , that might solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you given in your question use elasticsearch's Python API, and es.search do have a 10 thousand docs retrieving limit.

If you want to retrieve data more than 10,000, as suggested by dshockley in the comment, you can try scroll API. Or you can try elasticsearch's [scan helpers](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan), which automates a lot work with scroll API. For example, you won't need to get a scroll_id and pass it to the API, which will be necessary if you use scroll directly.

When use helpers.scan, you need to specify index and doc_type in the parameters when call the function, or write them in the query body. Note that, the parameter name is 'query' rather than 'body'.

Comment: thanks, using scroll api im able to get all the results in the csv file.